# How can I save controls in a dynamically created UserForm?

Tags: vba

I have code that will take data from a sheet and generate a form based on it, but I can't figure out how to 'save' the form after it's created. Here's the code that generates the form.

```
Sub UFInit()

Dim i As Long 'Counter to keep standardized checkbox names
Dim r As Range 'Range of cells to get checkbox captions
Dim cell As Range 'For the loop
Dim cb As MSForms.CheckBox 'Checkbox

Dim t As Double 'Top position for a checkbox
Dim l As Double 'Left position for a checkbox

Set r = Sheets("Sheet4").Range("A1:AAA100").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) 'Where my range is for captions

i = 1

For Each cell In r

    Set cb = UserFormX.controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "CheckBox" & i, True)
    cb.Caption = cell.Value
    cb.Name = Replace(Replace(cb.Caption, " ", ""), "-", "")
    cb.Top = cell.Row * 12.75
    cb.Left = 150 + cell.Column * 9.5

    If cell.Row * 12.75 > t Then t = (cell.Row * 12.75)
    If cell.Column * 9.5 > l Then l = (cell.Column * 10)

    i = i + 1

Next cell

UserForm1.Show

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "save"? Save so that when you close the workbook, the controls of the userform are permanently stored as part of the project? Or saved in the sense that when you close the form and later reopen it, the controls are in place? The former seems hard. It would be possible but would require scripting the VBA editor. The latter would be easier -- just hide the form rather than unloading it. The simplest workaround would be to just move this code to the useform's initialize event.

Comment: I want to be able to save it so I can go in later and change the code. It's basically a hierarchy tree where if I check one parent box, the children boxes are checked and it returns a value in a specific cell so it would be too complicated to figure out a way to dynamically generate the logic with it when I create it.

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388423/remove-controls-from-excel-userform-with-vbide . That particular question is about removing controls, but the underlying logic involves using the VBIDE object model (which requires an appropriate reference) to edit the userforms in a project.